# Import a javascript module as dynamic using typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I want to import a normal javascript module (e.g. *vhost*) into my node.js typescript file using CommonJS.
I can do this with the following line:

```
import vhost = require('vhost')
```

We assume that I can't find a .d.ts file on the internet, but I also don't want to write it by myself, so I just use the vhost variable without intellisense.

The compiler complains and complains:

[image]

How can I tell that I just want it to be 'dynamic' (like the C# *dynamic* keyword or 'var' in normal javascript) and use all of the things in the picture above?

I could create a vhost.d.ts file, but I don't know what to write in there:

```
declare module 'vash' {
    // what to write here?
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this out while typing the question, it was so easy that it is almost embarrassing, but maybe somebody has this problem too.

Just use var instead of import:

[image]

Comment: This is the *official* way to do it :)