# How to import a js Module as any. (Without any declaration file (d.ts))

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

So I want to import a *js* module in my *ts* app.

Is there a way to do this **without** making a [d.ts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html) file or if
not how to declare it as **any** in the [d.ts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html) file?

I am currently just ignoring this error with //@ts-ignore.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/30192129/16442705

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two cases here:

- You are using ESM modules, and only have `import(...)` available

```js
const module = (await import('module')) as any;
```

- You aren't using ESM modules, therefore you have access to `require(...)`

```js
const module = require('module') as any;
```